# Determine the type of a dynamic model

Tags: nhibernate

In NHibernate, you can map tables but without writing a class for them -- "dynamic models".  These are returned as Hashtable instances.

If you connect an event listener, for example an IPreDeleteEventListener, you can receive PreDeleteEvents.  These have:

- object[] DeletedState
- object Entity
- object Id
- IEntityPersister Persister
- IEventSource Session

I see no way here to get the type of the object.  Specifically, I want the `entity-name` of the `<nh:class>` (but `table` would be great, too).

It seems like there ought to be a way to get this, but I'm just not seeing it.  I'm being told that an event fired on an entity, and being handed a Hashtable and Id but I can't figure out what type it is.

Is there some method I'm just missing?  Or can anyone think of a usable workaround?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the entity-name using the `$type$` key on the dictionary/hashtable itself.

To get more granular details like table name, you'd probably have to find those in the runtime NHibernate configuration (looking up by the entity-name value).